# AngularJS app planning, displaying different content for different IPs

Tags: php, angularjs

I am building an AngularJS app, that will use a PhP PDO script in order to connect to a microsoft SQL database.

I used yeoman in order to scaffold my project (the angular generator), and a couple of pages in I now have to restrict some content. I want it to be shown only for users coming from certain IP adresses.

What would be the correct way to do this?

My idea was to try and setup a php script that returns a JSON object, whose content depends on what IP the user is connecting from. I tried googling around a bit and found nothing on how to do this (or if it's doable at all).

If anyone can point me towards related reading material, or suggest a better, simpler solution that is highly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$_SERVER`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) super global contains the user's IP (eg. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`), but you may want to opt for a log-in form instead as IP filtering is error-prone.